# Is there some kind of display control in .NET that can handle color codes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

It seems the only options available to do multi-color on a string is either a bunch of label controls cleverly grouped together or to use a RichTextBox and play with the font properties as text is added to the control.

What I am looking for instead is some kind of control that can render some style of control codes out as color.  Consider bash codes:

```sh
NORMAL='\e[0m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'
BLUE='\e[0;34m'

echo -e "This text is ${GREEN}green${NORMAL} and this text is ${BLUE}blue${NORMAL}"
```

In the above, the words 'green' and 'blue' will be colorized with their respective colors.  I was wondering if there was a control with some kind of feature like this, or will I have to code something myself?

Note, I only have the Express copy of VB 2010, and I would very much like to avoid third-party controls.

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, or something else?

Comment: @Gabe: VB.Net via VB Express 2010, and I am doing .NET 4.0 only.  So I assume WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifically looking for something that understands ANSI control codes, or just something that accepts markup? If you just want something that accepts markup, you can use the `RichTextBox.Rtf` property to set all the control codes and text with a single string.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277(v=office.10).aspx for the RTF specifications.

I would recommend programmatically generating a sample document, then reading the `Rtf` property and using the resulting RTF code as a template for what you should generate. For reference, here's a simple RTF document that has two color of text (plus the default) in Consolas (which fallback to Courier New):

```
{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Consolas {\*\falt Courier New};}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green176\blue80;}
\cf1 Hello\cf0 , \cf2 world\cf0 .
}
```

Comment: It would be a type of markup.  Sticking to the ANSI color range would be fine, too, as I don't anticipate using a ton of colors on a given string.  I guess RichTextBox.Rtf is one way.  There is no lighter-weight control available that could do this?

Comment: I can't imagine what would be more lightweight than the RTB and still let you control fonts on a per-character basis.

Comment: Well, I am looking through examples of RichTextBox.Rtf, and it looks like I would have to lug around a fair bit of string data just for the RTF header because you have to define the color tables and other properties.  And still baffled why no one at MS thought this was a good idea 10 years ago.  VB6, I can understand, but .NET?  Should've been in 1.0.

Comment: @Kumba - Microsoft does not think about it because there are many 3rd parties making a living out from these needs. The component eco-system/market is supposed to fill the gaps, IMHO. But you don't want 3rd party, which I can understand :-)

Comment: @Simon: Thus is the World according to Microsoft.  Open Source usually has these things taken care of...not that I've actually checked.  Though, even in my google searches so far, I haven't seen any third-party component that's strictly a label with markup syntax support.

Comment: @Kumba: It's not exactly clear what you're looking for. Do you wish MS made a text control where you can only select from a few fonts and only set the text to one of a set of predefined colors, but with a simpler markup language? If so, I think your idea is more unique than you thought.

Comment: @Gabe: The RTF spec is a lot larger than I originally thought.  Do you know off the top of your head what the font table bits look like if I want to define two, fixed-width fonts?  I want Consolas as the default with some ability to fall back to Courier New if Consolas is unavailable.  Or is that beyond the capabilities of the spec? (note: HTML can do this in <font> tags).

Comment: @Gabe:  The Bash example (the shell bash, from a Linux box) gives what I was looking for, a type of Markup syntax that lets me specify text colors in the middle of a string.  I was seeing if there was a control that might exist (because there's a ton of little libraries all over a Windows box), or if I am going to have to code something up myself.  I think RTF **might** do it, but I am going through the header specification and seeing how much effort it is to say, colorize two different words in a single sentence two different colors.

Comment: @Kumba: If you just use `{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern Consolas;}}` then it should use Consolas and fall back to Courier New if that's unavailable. At least that's what it does for me. You could also use `{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern Consolas;}{\f1\fmodern Courier New;}}` if you want.

Comment: @Gabe:  Looks like there's a `\falt` codeword, but RichTextBox.Rtf doesn't seem to like it.  Google is again useless in this context because it thinks I want 'fault' or something in Swedish, too.

Comment: @Gabe: Same for me, if I intentionally typo Consolas, it falls back to courier new.

Comment: @Gabe: You win.  This works for my purposes.  I'll find some way to spit out the RTF header, and then have my custom classes emit the appropriate color code based on what I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other options.  first you can paint text using the graphics object and [DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) method using any color font and style you want.  This however can be a pain.  The easiest way is to use a web browser control and use plain old html.

If you don't want to use RTF I wrote this little sample which will allow you to use RGB codes this is not complete solution as you would have to figure out a way to delmit the control chars.  If you wanted to test it create a form and drop a button and a rich text box on it.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str As String = "This text is {#00FF00}green{#000000} and this text is {#0000FF}blue{#000000}"
        PrintToRtf(str, RichTextBox1)

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub PrintToRtf(Str As String, RTB As RichTextBox)

        Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Str, "\{\#(?<Red>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(?<Green>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(?<Blue>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\}")


        Dim lp As Int32 = 0

        For Each mtc As Match In mc
            Dim subStr As String = Str.Substring(lp, mtc.Index - lp)

            Dim R, G, B As Byte
            R = Integer.Parse(mtc.Groups("Red").Value, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
            G = Integer.Parse(mtc.Groups("Green").Value, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
            B = Integer.Parse(mtc.Groups("Blue").Value, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)

            Dim clr As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B)


            RTB.SelectedText = subStr
            RTB.SelectionColor = clr
            lp = mtc.Index + mtc.Length
            RTB.Select(RTB.TextLength, 0)
        Next


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @rerun: I really, really want to avoid something as heavyweight as the web browser control.  I assume that's the embedded IE engine?

Comment: DrawString looks usable, though.  If I could combine that somehow with a Label control via inheritance, so that I retain access to all of Label's utility stuff to handle resizing, etc, and maybe a simple color code parser, That might cough up a usable control.  Has anything like that ever been tried before?

Comment: I guess I should add that I am surprised this kind of control has yet to be added to .NET.  Bash shells have had it for an extremely long time, and even something like an IRC client can do multiple colors inlined on a single line of text.  Think how mIRC handles color codes, etc.

Comment: It looks like the example in the [CharacterRange Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.characterrange.aspx) is really, really close to what I am after.  Except, instead of highlighting, changing the color.

Comment: The form application it self will be pretty hefty.  One control or another won't make much difference.  You would allways just spawn a console to output the data if you needed.

Comment: @rerun: Yeah, that is next on my list.  Auto-generating forms based on the fields in a custom class, because I really don't want to hardcode 50+ forms for all of my little classes.  And wind up with an executable fatter than Weird Al in 'Fat'.

Comment: Just the Windows forms App with one button is about 7 meg memory footprint add a browser control ups it to about 9.5 Adding a RTF box adds none.